# Software/games compatibility with Ubuntu from Windows platform w/out emulator

Tags: windows, software-sources, emulation, crossplatform

I would like to know if anyone has come across a stable and reliable Windows emulator for software only available to Windows platform for Ubuntu?  I know there is WINE, but still wondering about others or better?
Lastly, does anyone know of releases from the large game/software manufacturers to provide Ubuntu compatibility (i.e. Autodesk, EA Games, Bioware, World of Warcraft [sorry I don't know WoW's manuf.])?
And if not, how do we pressure these manuf's to provide an Ubuntu platform game/software?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [Wine Is Note a Emulator](https://www.winehq.org/about/) :) And should be able to do what you need (otherwise just run Windowz in a Virtual Machine or Dual Boot setup)

You can check the [Wine AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32314) to see if it will work - e.g. [WoW](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32314) should work with a small workaround, but Autodesk, EA Games and Bioware vary. Generally stuff that works on WinXP should work well.

You may also find [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/) helpful as installs apps with workarounds etc for you.

Not all software devs support Linux (and if they sometimes do not support it very well...), many of them do not support as they do not think it will make them money (WARNING: opinions), or are lazy, or they find it difficult to implement stuff so that the game's files cannot be taken apart and used/do stuff in OpenGL instead of DirectX etc....

Comment: Wilf, thanks for the quick reply.  I appreciate the other possibilities and will check them out.  Agreed with the 'make them money' comment; I just wish that weren't the case.  But maybe someday.  Thanks again.